# ESP32 Bluetooth Connection disconnects when finished with reading buffer

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino, disconnect, esp32

I'm programming an ESP32 to accept Bluetooth commands and send Bluetooth Data back to my phone using the Serial profile. For this I'm using the Arduino Espressif Bluetooth Serial Library. Whenever I send something to the ESP32 it processes it and then suddenly closes the Bluetooth Connection.

Up to know I have already tried various delays because I thought that maybe the processor was not keeping up with other stuff due to which it crashed. 
However when monitoring using the Serial Connection via USB it still keeps sending status updates.
Other than that I could not really find a solution (also on the Internet).

As I'm pretty much a beginner I did not want to try and build my own Serial Bluetooth Library.
The ESP does not crash when sending it the data. It also keeps processing the data which was sent. I can see that as it sends the chars I sent it via Bluetooth using  the Serial interface after having collected them.

The Connection cannot be rebuild after this incident, no matter how long I wait.

My Main function, containing the function call as well as a buffer to write the result to as I thought that maybe I was misusing that.

```
void loop() {

  if (ESP_BT.available() > 0)
  {
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(InputSize);
    getCurrentMessage(ESP_BT, buffer, InputSize);
    Serial.println(buffer);
    strncpy(currentMessage, buffer, InputSize);
    free(buffer);
  }
  if (millis() %2000 == 0){
    Serial.println("Debug");
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

The function which gets called which should read the inputBuffer of the BluetoothSerial into my Buffer.

```
void getCurrentMessage(BluetoothSerial ESP_BT, char* receivedChars, int InputSize)
{
 Serial.println("DEBUG: getCurrentMessageInit");
 static byte ndx = 0;

 char rc;

 while (ESP_BT.available() > 0){
   ESP_BT.println("DEBUG: Message Available");    
   Serial.println("DEBUG: Message Available");
   rc = ESP_BT.read();
   receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
   ndx++;
   delay(100);
   if (ndx >= InputSize){
     while(ESP_BT.available() > 0){
       ESP_BT.read();
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I would expect the Bluetooth Connection to keep working. This it does not do.
I also got the error Code "queue.c:1442 (xQueueGenericReceive)- assert failed!" When not using the delays and the ESP then rebooted. 
This it does not do after I included the delays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not call my Bluetooth Object by reference.
Instead of giving my function the Bluetooth Object I should point to it:

```
void getCurrentMessage(BluetoothSerial* ESP_BT, char* receivedChars, int InputSize)
{
 Serial.println("DEBUG: getCurrentMessageInit");
 static byte ndx = 0;

 char rc;

 while (ESP_BT->available() > 0){
   ESP_BT->println("DEBUG: Message Available");    
   Serial.println("DEBUG: Message Available");
   rc = ESP_BT.read();
   receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
   ndx++;
   delay(100);
   if (ndx >= InputSize){
     while(ESP_BT->available() > 0){
       ESP_BT->read();
     }
   }
 }
}
```